# How to traverse nested lists in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, data-structures

I have this code, reading corpus of documents, and put them in java data-structure.

```
  public List<List<Integer>> corpus;
    corpus = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    numDocuments = 0;
    numWordsInCorpus = 0;           
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
            int indexSentence = -1;
            int indexWord = -1;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToCorpus));
            for (String doc; (doc = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                if (doc.trim().length() == 0)
                    continue;

                List<List<Integer>> document = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
                String [] sentenceStrs = doc.split("\t");
                for(String sentenceStr: sentenceStrs){
                   List<Integer> sntence = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                    indexSentence += 1;
                    String[] words = sentenceStr.trim().split(" ");
                    for (String word : words) {
                        if (word2IdVocabulary.containsKey(word)) {
                            sntence.add(word2IdVocabulary.get(word));
                        }
                        else {
                            indexWord += 1;
                            word2IdVocabulary.put(word, indexWord);
                            id2WordVocabulary.put(indexWord, word);
                            sntence.add(indexWord);
                        }
                    }
                    document.add(sntence);
                    numWordsInCorpus += sntence.size();
                }
                numDocuments++;
                corpus.addAll(document);
            }
    }
```

I need to get every document in the corpus, and for each document I want to read every word index. 
When the corpus got thousands documents, how to traverse these nested lists with fast run?

Comment: Just use a nested `for` loop, but your code won't work because you keep adding the *same* `sntence` list to `document`, so every sentence in the document will be the full list of words.

Comment: @Andreas why is the same sentence? Every line in the corpus file is representing document. How could I use the nested for loop to get the words index from each document in the corpus.

Comment: Let's say `doc` is `A B\tC D`, which splits to `A B` and `C D`. Word `A` and `B` indexes (0 and 1) are added to `sntence` which is then `[0,1]` and `sntence` is added to `document` which is then `[ [0,1] ]`. Word `C` and `D` indexes (2 and 3) are added to *same* `sntence` (now `[0,1,2,3]`) and it is added to `document` *again* (now `[ [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3] ]`).

Comment: @Andreas how could I fix this problem, and I want to read them again.

Comment: @Andreas I just updated that, by defining sentences lists inside the for-loop. How to read them back from the corpus.

Comment: `for (List<Integer> sntence : corpus) { for (Integer indexWord : sntence) { /*code here*/ } }`. As I said, nested `for` loop.

Comment: @Andreas how about the document list ?

Comment: You lost that when you used `addAll()`, which *merges* the lists. Change to `add()` and make `corpus` a `List<List<List<Integer>>.`.